# Constant size array initalization with sizeof

Tags: c, arrays

Why does the following work just fine with gcc c99

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int b[sizeof a / sizeof *a] = {0};
```

But this gives compilation errors

```
int n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
int b[n] = {0};
```

Error

```
file.c:14:2: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
file.c:14:2: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
file.c:14:2: warning: (near initialization for 'b') [enabled by default]
```

Comment: `sizeof a / sizeof *a` is a compile time constant whereas `n` isn't (even though it's value is computed at compile time).

Comment: You are not allowed to [initialize a vla](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18854398/1708801)

Comment: As long as the desired constant is in the range of `int` (and is, in fact, constant), a possible workaround (avoiding a VLA) is `enum { n = sizeof a / sizeof *a }; int b[n] = {0};`

Comment: @Lundin I still get the error. gcc 463

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example works because `sizeof a / sizeof *a` is a constant expression, and it's OK to be used as array dimension.

In the second example, `n` is NOT a constant expression, so the compiler treats `b` as a definition of variable length array, the error is saying VLAs may not be initialized.

Comment: Makes sense but seems illogical to me. I would hope the compiler is smart enough to figure out that n is constant.

Comment: @arynaq: I don't know the reason why the standard doesn't allow it, but possibly it was because it introduces UB: `int b[n] = { 1, 2, 3 };` -- what if `n` is smaller than 3? (There already is UB anyway for VLAs if the size is 0 or negative, however.)

Answer (score 3):

`n` is a variable unlike `sizeof a / sizeof *a` because latter is calculate at compile time.

`int b[n]` declares a variable length array. You can't initialize it by using initializer list. You can use a loop or `memeset` function to initialize all of its elements to `0`.

```
memset(b, 0, sizeof(b));
```

Comment: Ah this seems a bit more elegant than a loop!